# What is a method to figure out what x is in the equation "1 = secx"?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

As the title suggests I am doing Trigonometric substitution.  I am okay with everything until we have to change the boundaries of the integration.  The answer I believe is pi/3, but I don't know how to do that without using a calculator.

Comment: From the definition of $\sec$, this is equivalent to $\cos x = 1$. Now look at the unit circle.

Comment: Guess and check.

Comment: @user126599 Hi, I would suggest removing this question or accepting the answer to remove the question from the "unanswered" section.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x} $. Hence,

$$ \sec x = 1 \iff \cos x = 1 \iff x = 2n \pi $$

for $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.